# SQL query doesn't show al the records

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to show all the records from services regardles of if they excist in service_overview. But it only shows 3 records, that's becaus they are the only ones that aren't picked in any record in service_overview.

```
SELECT *
FROM services
LEFT JOIN service_overview ON service_overview.ServiceID = services.serviceID
WHERE service_overview.OverviewID IS NULL OR service_overview.OverviewID = 1
ORDER BY services.serviceID
```

This returns [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6s0r.png)
As you can see this doesn't return all the records from services servicid's 1, 3, 4, 5.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the condition in the `ON` clause, not the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM services s LEFT JOIN
     service_overview so
     ON so.ServiceID = s.serviceID AND so.OverviewID = 1
ORDER BY s.serviceID;
```

The problem with your query is that it filters out services that have an `OverviewID` other than `1` -- unless they also have `1`.